# How can I transform a series object (generated with iloc) into a single-row dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Suppose I have a `pd.DataFrame` object. Suppose further that I've used the `iloc` method to extract a single row from it as a `pd.Series` object. How can I transform that `pd.Series` object into a single-row `pd.DataFrame` object?

Here's a small reproducible example of what I'm talking about:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Generating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'colA':['a','b','c','d','e'],
                   'colB':[11,22,33,44,55]})

# Extracting a single row from the DataFrame as
# a pd.Series object
row_as_series = df.iloc[0]

print(row_as_series)
# id      1
# colA    a
# colB    11
# Name: 0, dtype: object

print(type(row_as_series))
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(row_as_series.shape)
# (3,)
```

How can I reshape the `row_as_series` object above into a single-row DataFrame? Here is what I'd like the output to look like

```
   id colA  colB
0   1    a    11
```

### Note about `iloc[[0]]`

I know that I can use `iloc` and double square brackets to generate a DataFrame-like output instead of a Series-like output, as seen below:

```py
row_as_df = df.iloc[[0]]

print(row_as_df)
#    id colA  colB
# 0   1    a    11

print(type(row_as_series))
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print(row_as_series.shape)
# (1, 3)
```

However, suppose I can't change the part of the code with the `iloc` command. Suppose that I'm only allowed to edit the part of the code that is "downstream" from the `iloc[]` method. I'm still curious about how to go from a Series object to a single-row DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the Series object inside a list and feed it into `pd.DataFrame()`, as seen below:

```py
single_row_df = pd.DataFrame([row_as_series])

print(single_row_df)
#    id colA  colB
# 0   1    a    11

print(type(single_row_df))
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print(single_row_df.shape)
# (1, 3)
```

### Extra info: building `pd.DataFrames` with multiple rows

This wasn't part of the original question, but it's worth mentioning: If you add multiple `pd.Series` objects into the list, they will be read as multiple rows. Here's a quick example:

```py
temp_df = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[0],
                        df.iloc[2],
                        df.iloc[4]])

print(temp_df)
#    id colA  colB
# 0   1    a    11
# 2   3    c    33
# 4   5    e    55

print(type(temp_df))
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print(temp_df.shape)
# (3, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative you can do `groupby` with `get_group`

```
df.groupby(level=0).get_group(0)
   id colA  colB
0   1    a    11
```

If need covert

```
df.iloc[0].to_frame().T
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the answer! This seems to work just fine when I'm applying it to the original DataFrame (i.e., before extracting the row using `iloc`). However, my question is more specifically pointed at the situation when I **already** extracted a row using `iloc` and need to deal with that. I tried doing `row_as_series.groupby(level=0).get_group(0)` and it raised a `KeyError`.

Comment: @FelipeD. ah ok updated